# can an RPM spec file "include" other files?

Tags: linux, scripting, rpm, rpm-spec

Is there a kind of "include" directive in RPM spec? I couldn't find an answer by googling.

**Motivation**: I have a RPM spec template which the build process modifies with the version, revision and other build-specific data. This is done by `sed` currently. I think it would be cleaner if the spec would `#include` a build-specific definitions file, which would be generated by the build process, so I don't need to search and replace in the spec.

If there is no `include`, is there an idiomatic way to do this (quite common, I believe) task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RPM does not support includes.

I have solved similar problems with either m4 macro processor or by just concatenating parts of spec (when the "include" was at the beginning).

If you only need to pass a few variables at build time, and not include several lines from another file, you can run

```
rpmbuild --define 'myvar SOMEVALUE' -bb myspec.spec
```

and you can use %myvar in the spec.

Comment: thanks! `--define` is the second intuitive solution I felt should be there

Comment: Thanks! `--define` is not documented in my version of rpmbuild (4.9.1.1) but it works. I looked for something like that for hours!!!

Comment: recent rpm 4.12+ support load which loads macrofile, for example you can do something like this `%{?load:%{SOURCE1}}` see

http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/ruby.git/tree/ruby.spec?id=b9da2e689a47e432a4272b43c849a9a818965bbb#n92

Answer (score 21):

Sufficiently recent versions of rpmbuild certainly do support %include:

```
%include common.inc
```

Unfortunately, they aren't very smart about it -- there is no known set of directories, in which it will look for the requested files, for example. But it is there and variables are expanded, for example:

```
%include %{_topdir}/Common/common.inc
```

Comment: thanks Misha, fortunately this is off my hands now to a proper CM :)

Comment: It would be very much appreciated if somebody would comment about from which version `%include` is fully supported.

Comment: The earliest mention I can find of `%include` is in the [release notes for 4.8](http://rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.8.0), and that implies a fix to a feature that already existed. The release notes for 4.4.x, 4.6 and 4.7 don't mention `%include` at all, implying the feature was introduced in 4.4.2 (July 2005) at the latest. As of 2018, I think it is safe to assume your version of RPM is *seriously* in need of upgrading if it does not support `%include`.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this same issue recently.  I wanted to define multiple sub-packages that were similar, but each varied just slightly (they were language-specific RPMs).  I didn't want to repeat the same boiler-plate stuff for each sub-package.

Here's a generic version of what I did:

```
%define foo_spec() %{expand:%(cat '%{myloc}/main-foo.spec')}
%{foo_spec bar}
%{foo_spec baz}
%{foo_spec qux}
```

The use of `%{expand}` ensures that `%(cat)` is only executed a single time, when the macro is defined.  The content of the main-foo.spec file is then three times, and each time `%1` in the main-foo.spec file expands to each of `bar`, `baz` and `qux`, in turn, allowing me to treat it as a template.  You could easily expand this to more than one parameter, if you have the need (I did not).

Answer (score 4):

For the underlying issue, there maybe two additional solutions that are present in all *rpm* versions that I am aware of.

1. Subpackages
2. `macro` and `rpmrc` files.

### Subpackages

Another alternative (and perhaps the "**RPM way**") is to use [*sub-packages*](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch10s04.html). [*Maximum RPM*](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-subpack.html) also has information and examples of *subpackages*.

I think the question is trying to structure something like,

- two spec files; say **rpm_debug.spec** and **rpm_production.spec**
- both use `%include common.spec`

*debug* and *production* could also be *client* and *server*, etc.  For the examples of redefining a variable, each *subpackage* can have it's own list of variables.

### Limitations

The main advantage of *subpackages* is that only **one build** takes place; This may also be a disadvantage.  The *debug* and *production* example may highlight this.  That can be worked around using `strip` to create variants *or* compiling twice with different output; perhaps using `VPATH` with Gnu Make).  Having to compile large packages and then only have simple variations, like with/without developer info, like `headers`, *static libraries*, etc. can make you appreciate this approach.

### Macros and Rpmrc

*Subpackages* don't solve the problem of *structural* defines that you wish for an entire **rootfs** hierarchy, or larger collection of RPMs.  We have `rpmbuild --showrc` for this.  You can have a large amount of *variables* and *macros* defined by altering `rpmrc` and `macros` when you run `rpm` and `rpmbuild`.  From the `man` page,

```
   rpmrc Configuration
       /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc
       /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/rpmrc
       /etc/rpmrc
       ~/.rpmrc

   Macro Configuration
       /usr/lib/rpm/macros
       /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/macros
       /etc/rpm/macros
       ~/.rpmmacros
```

I think these two features can solve all the problems that `%include` can.  However, `%include` is a familiar concept and was probably added to make **rpm** more full-featured and developer friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Which version are you talking about?  I currently have %include filename.txt in my spec file and it seems to work just like the C #include directive.

```
> rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.8.1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can include the `*.inc` files from the SOURCES directory (`%_sourcedir`):

```
Source1: common.inc

%include %{SOURCE1}
```

In this way they will go automatically into **SRPMS**.

Comment: This is a lot like [Міша](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1157384/) and [Digitalsky's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136056/can-an-rpm-spec-file-include-other-files/7113577#7113577).  I think it only works in newer `rpm` versions; so if you have a newer `rpm`, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I've used scripts (name your favorite) to take a template and create the spec file from that. Also, the `%files` tag can import a file that is created by another process, e.g. Python's `bdist-rpm`.