# RPM: include a set of constants

Tags: bash, rpm, rpm-spec

So [I already know how to define macros and include these in my main spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341189/rpm-returning-values-from-included-rpm-macro) file. However, I also want to be able to include a set of constants; something like this:

*hostnames.spec*

```sh
%define HOST1 host1
%define HOST2 host2
...
```

*main.spec*

```sh
%include hostnames.spec

...

checkHost %{HOST1}
```

Is there a way to do this with RPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can:

- According to *[More "RPM argh" or how to use %includes properly](http://ramblingfoo.blogspot.com/2007/07/more-rpm-argh-or-how-to-use-includes.html)* , `rpm` (no version mentioned) allows `%include`, provided that you list (and package) the included files as *sources* in the RPM.  The blog entry goes on to mention that this complicates the include path, by making it refer to `../SOURCES` (under your `rpmbuild` directory) rather than within the build-directory.
- Another (*[can an RPM spec file “include” other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919211/4518274)*) asserts that "Sufficiently recent versions of rpmbuild certainly do support %include", and reiterates the problem about the include-directories.
- "Sufficiently recent" might be not a problem, since the feature is mentioned in a 2002 report about RPM 3.0.6 (*[Two issues related to %if and %include](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2002-September/msg00039.html)*).

Comment: Thanks! Based on the "RPM argh" article, I've figured out that in our production environment which has rpm 4.8.0 bundled, you have to move your spec file to `SOURCES` and also have to list it as a source file in order to get the `%include` directive working. I actually used `%include` in `%pre`, this way the macros are available in `%post` and `%preun` too. With 4.11.0 I just had to use `%include` "C-style" on the first line of the spec file and It was enough to have the file in `SPECS` without listing it as source.